# Set a custom domain for a storage account using Azure Powershell

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-resource-manager, azure-storage-account

Is it possible to set up a custom domain for a Azure Resource Manager (ARM) storage account using Azure Powershell? If so, how?

I tried to set up a custom domain through the Azure Preview Web Portal but that functionality does not yet exist for the new resource manager storage accounts.

Using this [documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azps-1-0-pre/), I am able to login and see the properties of my new RM storage account, but I am unsure how to update the `CustomDomain` property. I expected to find an example/documentation of how this worked with the old storage accounts, but I have not found anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution that worked for us. You can use the `Set-AzureRmStorageAccount` command to set properties on an existing storage group. Not sure how I missed this one.

```
Set-AzureRmStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName "<YOUR RESOURCE GROUPNAME>" -Name "<YOUR STORAGE ACCOUNT NAME>" -CustomDomainName <YOUR.CUSTOM.DOMAIN> -UseSubDomain $true
```

Answer (score 1):

In case, like me, you get ResourceGroupNotFound do following command to select your subscription before (you get your subscription id in the Azure Portal):

```
Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId <YourSubscriptionID>
```