# Clear/change CustomDomainName for storage account using Powershell

Tags: azure-storage, azure-powershell

I want to setup a custom domain for a azure storage account(v2?, not classic).

[With this answer I managed to use powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33353612/33236) to set it up for one domain and one storage account.
For another domain and another storage account I thought I had it configured correctly but when I try to configure it now I get this error:

```
Set-AzureRmStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName "ExampleGroup" -Name "test" -CustomDomainName test.example.com -UseSubDomain $true

Set-AzureRmStorageAccount : CustomDomainNameAlreadySet: Custom domain name is already set.  Current value must be cleared before setting a new value.
+ Set-AzureRmStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName "ExampleGroup" -Name " ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Set-AzureRmStorageAccount], CloudException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Management.Storage.SetAzureStorageAccountCommand
```

The only [answer](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/3d5895f0-d0a5-47d8-aebc-7f6f7dc4bc23/cannot-change-custom-domain-associated-with-azure-storage-account?forum=windowsazuredata) I've found implies that one should use the classical portal which is not an option as v2 storage accounts does not show up there.

How can I clear the CustomDomainName value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment if you have a custom domain name set and want to replace it, you have to unregister it first. To unregister it, set the CustomDomainName to an empty string and don't send UseSubDomain.